# I have duplicates values in my database how to get only one

Tags: python, mysql, ajax, django

I have a catalog and I have a lot of duplicat registers, I need to get only one of the register, 'cause I will do some nested DropDownLists so I just need one of the values. 
I have no idea how to do it, I'm using Django with and ajax call to bring the data from the database.

view.py

```
def adendumSeach(request):
    if request.POST.has_key('grupname') and request.is_ajax():
        x = request.POST['grupname']
        y = adendum.objects.filter(adendum_credencial=x)
        formulario = serializers.serialize('json', y)
        return HttpResponse(formulario, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        return render_to_response('ExpedienteDetalle.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

ajax.js

```
function adendum(idgrupo) {
      $.ajax({
            url: "/adendum_search",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                grupname: idgrupo,
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'
            },
                 success: function (json) {
                var jsonResponse = eval(json);
                $.each(jsonResponse, function(index, element){
                    $("#aden").css("display", "block");
                    $("#thconsultas").css("display", "block");
            }); ;
                 },
             error: function (xhr, errmsg, err) {
                alert(xhr.status + "  Inside error :    " + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
     }
```

Comment: can `distinct` help You?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_key` is deprecated.

`x` and `y` are bad variables names.

`adendum` class must be UpperCase

as @oleg said, use [distinct](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)

```
def adendumSeach(request):
    if 'grupname' in request.POST  and request.is_ajax():
        grupname = request.POST['grupname']
        adendum_list = adendum.objects.filter(adendum_credencial=grupname).distinct()
        formulario = serializers.serialize('json', adendum_list)
        return HttpResponse(formulario, mimetype="application/json")
    else:
        return render_to_response('ExpedienteDetalle.html',
        context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```